# Restricting var to result of #keyPath()

Tags: ios, swift

I really like an idea of using **#keyPath()** for safety reason. Now, I want to give my enum case an associated value with the name of some property.

My question is - are there any ways to force compilation check on associated value to give me a guarantee that this path is existed?

Though it doesn't work, what I want is something like this:

```
enum MissingKeysError {
    case propIsMissing(checkedExistedPropertyHere: String)
}
```

I understand that **#keyPath** only returns me a string, but I really would like to use similar mechanism for my associated value.

Comment: you can apply `#keypath(...)` only on such properties which could be represented in Objective-C (`@objc`); on the other hand you are able to check whether the class's property exists or not in runtime by using reflections in Swift; you can take a look at [`Mirror(...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror) docs on Apple Site.

Comment: @holex, thank you for your comment, but won't it be a runtime check instead? I want compile time, only this way it makes sense

Comment: as far as I'm concerned (and I understand your concerns well), Xcode9 will drop you an error / warning about any mismatch in compile-time when you use `#keyPath(...)`; you don't need to do any extra for that... and you can use the autocomplete for populating the _keyPath's_ parameter, what also helps reducing the typos.